# Mysql Change username query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some trouble with this, I need to change a username because
it is a privilege for admins on my website however when it gets to the mysql side of it, I got no idea so, this is how it works:
The admin fills in a form (username & new username)
I need it to find the usernames id and then change the username with chosen new username in the entered form
If this helps here's my code so far

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';
protect_page();
admin_protect();
include 'includes/overall/header.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('username', 'add');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
            break 1;
        }
    }
}

    if (empty($errors) === false) {
        if (user_exists($_POST['cusername']) === true) {
            $errors[] = 'Sorry, the username \'' . $_POST['username'] . '\' is taken!';
        }
    }
?>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
    echo 'The username has been succesfully changed!';
} else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        $cusername = array(
            'username'      => $_POST['username'],
            'cusername'         => $_POST['cusername']
        );

function cusername($cusername) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."' SET          username = ".$_POST['cusername']."");
}  
        cusername($cusername);
        header('Location: changeusername.php?success');
        exit();

    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
?>

<h1>Admin Access Only</h1>
<p>Change a username</p>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <ul>
                <li>
                    Username*:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="username">
                </li>
                <li>
                    New Username*:<br>
                    <input type="text" name="cusername">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="submit" value="Update">
                </li>
        </ul>
        </form>
<?php
}
include 'includes/overall/footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). This is especially bad, since your queries are modifying user information. consider a `cusername` of `username, rights='superuser'`...

Answer (score 0):

In the UPDATE statement you need the SET first, followed by the WHERE.  But as Marc B pointed out, you always need to be careful to sanitize and escape user entered data.  Don't trust anything the user gives you!  In this case you can use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) although the function is now deprecated and you should consider changing your database handling code to MySQLi or PDO_MySQL.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cusername'])."' WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'");
```